# Azure function HTTP Request 404 when published to Azure through Docker and Visual Studio

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

I'm attempting to learn some more about Azure Functions 2.0 and Docker containers to publish to my Azure instance. I followed to tutorial below with the only difference being that I published with docker to a container registry in azure using visual studio 2019.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

This all worked correctly and I was able to start my container and visit the site. However, in the example you can visit /api/function1 and get a response. This works on my localhost but on the live site it returns a 404. It seems that /api/function1 is not reachable after being published.

The app itself returns this when visiting the IP itself so I know it is working. Do I need to do something else in Azure to expose my APIs?

[image: Azure screenshot working default page]

My container log only shows this.

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I grabbed my dockerfile from here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/master/host/2.0/nanoserver-1809/Dockerfile

```
# escape=`

# Installer image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 AS installer-env

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Retrieve .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 2.2.402

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet.zip https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$Env:DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-sdk-$Env:DOTNET_SDK_VERSION-win-x64.zip; `
    $dotnet_sha512 = '0fa3bf476b560c8fc70749df37a41580f5b97334b7a1f19d66e32096d055043f4d7ad2828f994306e0a24c62a3030358bcc4579d2d8d439d90f36fecfb2666f6'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $dotnet_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -DestinationPath dotnet; `
    Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 `
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true `
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true `
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip `
    PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false `
    HOST_COMMIT=69f124faed40d20d9d8e5b8d51f305d249b21512 `
    BUILD_NUMBER=12858

RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile host.zip https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/archive/$Env:HOST_COMMIT.zip; `
    Expand-Archive host.zip .; `
    cd azure-functions-host-$Env:HOST_COMMIT; `
    /dotnet/dotnet publish /p:BuildNumber=$Env:BUILD_NUMBER /p:CommitHash=$Env:HOST_COMMIT src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\WebJobs.Script.WebHost.csproj --output C:\runtime


# Runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2.7-nanoserver-1809

COPY --from=installer-env ["C:\\runtime", "C:\\runtime"]

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=C:\approot `
    WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=localhost:80

CMD ["dotnet", "C:\\runtime\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll"]
```

Here's my function1 code for my azure function

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string productid = req.Query["productid"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            productid = productid ?? data?.product;

            Product newProduct = new Product()
            {
                ProductNumber = 0,
                ProductName = "Unknown",
                ProductCost = 0
            };
            if (Convert.ToInt32(productid) ==1)
            {
                newProduct = new Product()
                {
                    ProductCost = 100,
                    ProductName = "Lime Tree",
                    ProductNumber = 1
                };
            }
            else if(Convert.ToInt32(productid) == 2) 
            {
                newProduct = new Product()
                {
                    ProductCost = 500,
                    ProductName = "Lemon Tree",
                    ProductNumber = 2
                };
            }
            return productid != null
                ? (ActionResult)new JsonResult(newProduct)
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
```

Here's a photo of my container running with my image.

[image: Container image]

I'm new to this so any advice would be helpful for sure!

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to push your docker image to Azure Container Registry or Docker Hub.

Comment: @Thiago Hey Thiago, It's up there now! It's running as an actual container it just doesnt have the /api/ part. I edited my question to include a photo of my running container.

Comment: at what part are you putting your custom DLL into the docker image? did I miss that?

Comment: @silent I'm not too sure, that could be what I am missing. I thought visual studio with a docker build would do that automatically. How do I manually make sure it gets in there? Is that a dockerfile change?

Comment: There is no magic happening outside the docker build ;) I’ll look for an example tomorrow

Comment: @silent Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@silent's answer was correct - Linux containers are the way to go for Azure Functions. My environment wasn't set up correctly for Linux containers but once I got a correct environment this worked out of the box.

Here's my latest DockerFile for another project that uses Linux Containers

## See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionTestAppLinux/FunctionTestAppLinux.csproj", "FunctionTestAppLinux/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionTestAppLinux/FunctionTestAppLinux.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionTestAppLinux"
RUN dotnet build "FunctionTestAppLinux.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FunctionTestAppLinux.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/app
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know if you really need to (or want to) run Functions on Windows containers. If you want to run in a container, I would probably opt for Linux. For that, this is an example Dockerfile. It does build on top of the Microsoft-provided base image. So you don't have to build that from scratch.

I'm sure there is also a base image for Windows that is already build. If you need it, just look around in the similiar repo I guess.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish myfunction -c Release -o myfunction /out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=build-env /app/ao-backendfunctions/out .

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/app
ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

The important part is `RUN dotnet publish myfunction -c Release -o myfunction /out`. Replace myfunction with the (folder) name of your actual Function.

Comment: is right. Azure functions like this aren't working for me on a windows container. I was originally trying to get this to work on a Windows Server VM that crashes when I switch to a Linux containers because of environment issues. Much easier to avoid all that and use a machine that can run Linux Containers.

Comment: Kind of forcing a square peg into a round hole. I used my laptop (not VM) and the out of the box visual studio publish worked correctly. I would recommend using Linux containers going forward for Azure Functions. There was a reason Visual studio didn't let me add docker support for windows.